# spark-submit with zip packages throw error on native modules like psycopg2-binary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, python-packaging

I am developing some basic spark jobs on pyspark. The spark job is leveraging a common python for utilities and data upserts. To allow for local testing I am packaging the python module as zip package. The zip package is built via the requirements.txt file as shown below

```
buildzip:

    poetry export -f requirements.txt --without-hashes -o requirements.txt
    poetry run pip install --use-feature=in-tree-build . -r requirements.txt -t package_tmp
    cd package_tmp && find . -name "*.pyc" -delete && zip -r "test_package" . && cd .. && cp package_tmp/test_package.zip dist/ && rm -r package_tmp
```

The output zip package `test_package.zip` is used in the local spark-submit as follows

```
spark-submit --py-files dist/test_package.zip /<path>/job.py
```

The above process works fine except for the places where I need database access using `psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.2"`. I get the error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'`

I understand that this error is due to packaging the native modules on zip folder. Unfortunately `spark-submit` on local does not take the `whl` packages.

How do I package these native modules under zip so that I test my spark jobs locally?

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the documentation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

You have to use the --archive option to add your environment packaged with venv-pack. That worked for me after hours of searching

1. Create a virtual environment `virtualenv my_env`
2. Active your new virtual env `source venv/bin/activate`
3. Install your current requirements `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. Install venv-pack `pip install venv-pack`
5. Create a packaged version of your current environment `venv-pack -o my_env.tar.gz`. This will create the file that will be sent to the spark-submit command
6. Deactivate your virtual env `deactivate`
7. Call your spark-submit command with your newly created packaged env `spark-submit --archives my_env.tar.gz#environment my_job.py`

It is important to notice the `#environment` after the package name, this will determine the location in which the tag.gz will be unpackaged while running spark.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).